# design for updating information in a view of listview

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

i have an app that has a listview.  each view inside of the listview has custom xml and has buttons checkboxes and textviews.  i have to get the previous saved settings for the checkboxes from an sqlite database and set them. and if the user changes the checkboxes or radio buttons i have to save those settings in the database.

tried several different ways to do this and most resulted in error and would not display the correct setting for checkboxes when coming back to the page.

what finally worked is the design shown below. where i put any database calls as close as possible to the actual view.   however it looks like if there is many rows in the listview it would make many calls to the database and it could get slow.

is my design correct or is there a better way

psudocode

```
 onCreate


 instantiate arraylist adapter and set adapter to view

 end onCreate

 arrayadapter class

 getView(){

 call databsase and get previous settings for checkboxes in this view and
 set the checkboxes to show checked or not depending on database saved settings


 onClicklistener or oncheckedchanged listener for getting checkbox positions if changed

 call database and set method to store updated positions of checkbox, radiobutton or spinner


}


 end arrayadapter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct and your concern is warranted. I can suggest you the following method, but its performance will have to be tested:

```
onCreate

    instantiate arraylist adapter and set adapter to view

end onCreate

arrayadapter class

    getView(){

        call databsase and get previous settings for checkboxes in this view and
        set the checkboxes to show checked or not depending on database saved settings

        ----> Create two ArrayLists: ArrayList<Boolean> for CheckBoxes 
        ----> and ArrayList<Integer> for RadioButtons.
        ----> Fill these lists using the values from the databse

        onClicklistener or oncheckedchanged listener for getting checkbox positions if changed

        call database and set method to store updated positions of checkbox, radiobutton or spinner

        ----> Here, update the lists, not the database. 
        ----> Execute a AsyncTask to update the database whenever the lists change. 

    }


end arrayadapter
```

Answer (score 0):

Another think you can do is to load data from database in Activity.onStart() and save it back in Activity onPause(). All other time use ArrayList to track changes in UI.

In that case you will have this heavy db operations much rarely during the Activity life cycle.